# How to trigger `exports.handler` in atom editor

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

This may be extremely silly.

I was using aws lambda functions for a while, and they usually start with `exports.handler = (event, context, callback)`. AWS already has a test button where you can load in JSON and it tests it by providing JSON as an input to `exports.handler`, ad then from within the handler, formatting is done on the inputs, therse a bunch of `console.logs()` that are printed and so on.

I recently moved to atom editor, and moved all my code over from lambda. I am using Atom Runner to run my JS code.. however I realised when I run it, all I get is: `Exited with code=0 in 0.745 seconds`. Basically it isn't running at all.

How do I trigger `exports.handler` in Atom Editor? do I have to store JSON in a new file and call it in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda is wrapping your code, and knows to call that function `.handler()` when a request comes in. This is Lamba's contract with its users, but is not a universal thing. Right now Atom-Runner is just reading all of your code in, but then no functions are being called.

If you run `node index.js` (replace index with your filename) on the command line it will do the same thing Atom-Runner is doing.

You need a top level function call, for example adding `exports.handler()` at the very bottom of your file should work. If you want `events`, `context`, and `callback` to be defined you have to pass them yourself when you make that call (by reading in your JSON file or whatever you want).